# Update to play 2.0.2 - Address already in used with akka remote actor

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm updating my application to play-2.0.2.

I have a problem when deploying an Akka remote actor :

```
[error] p.c.ActionInvoker - Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteServer.start(Server.scala:53) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport.start(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:73) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:95) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:568) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:575) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.bind(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:140) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleServerSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:92) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66) ~[netty.jar:na]
[error] a.r.RouterConfig$$anon$1 - Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteServer.start(Server.scala:53) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport.start(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:73) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:95) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:568) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:575) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.bind(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:140) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleServerSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:92) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66) ~[netty.jar:na]
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: Thrown(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out)
```

When calling the following code on application startup :

```
ActorSystem system = Akka.system();

Address addr = new Address("akka", "application");
defaultInstance = system.actorOf(new Props(TheActor.class).withDeploy(new Deploy(new RemoteScope(addr))), "theActor");
```

When this configuration in application.conf :

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
 }
}
```

The same setup works fine on play-2.0.1.

Is there some configuration change to make in work on play-2.0.2 ?

Thank you.

Comment: Similar problem here when creating a promise using `concurrent.Akka.future`.

Comment: On startup with play 2.0.2 initially `RemoteServerStarted@akka://promise@127.0.0.1:9002` is created.  Formerly this was `application@127.0.0.1`.  When any code is run that creates an actor, I get the `Address already in use` error.

Comment: I created a sample application that produces this error.  See https://gist.github.com/3063509.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe try this: from the [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/remoting.html), you can set the port to 0 to use an automatically chosen one:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I can deploy the application this way, but I need to know what the port is to call my remote actor from another server.

Comment: After a quick Google search, it seems that it is possible using `akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.getExternalAddressFor` (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/akka-user/POngjU9UpK8). Then you can write a controller to get this address from your other server using a http request.